# larger than life-sized

Tags: terminology

Can I call a chair that is about 13 feet tall (a statue) 'life sized'? As in 'she is standing next to a life-sized chair'? Seemed appropriate to me at first, but then I realized (after checking its definition) 'life sized' would mean the chair is of a normal chair's size, which isn't correct. But it does sound right. Is it appropriate to use 'life sized' here, or is there a word for 'larger than life-sized' that's more suitable here?

I have vague recollections of hearing 'life sized' used to describe a much larger replica of a small object. As in a 'life-sized' apple to mean an apple (statue) that's literally as big as a person. Could it be acceptable in some cute/sarcastic sense?

If 'life sized' is not appropriate, is there any way to describe it (the chair) without making it seem like I'm complaining that the chair is too big, or bigger than it should, or suggesting anything negative?

Comment: You can say the chair is *larger than life* or *oversized*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thanks. I just added some details.

Comment: @YosefBaskin _larger than life_ Persons only, wholly figurative: If someone is larger than life, that person attracts a lot of attention because they are more exciting or interesting than most people: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/larger-than-life Where is that literal usage of yours found?

Comment: You could say that your 13' chair was 'giant-sized' or 'giant-size'. Personally I would prefer that to 'larger than life sized' for an inanimate object but 'larger than life sized' (note, not 'larger than life') would be applicable to an apple because an apple is, or at least has been, living, growing and ripening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective "*life-size*" describes the size of things as being normal.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/life-size?q=life-size)) **life-size** adjective  /ˈlaɪf saɪz/ (also life-sized)
> ​the same size as a person or thing really is
> ♦ a life-size statue

There is an adjective that can be taken to mean "of size bigger than normal" but it means also "too big", so that connotation remains attached to the word.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/oversized?q=oversized)  **oversized** adjective  /ˈəʊvəsaɪzd/ (also less frequent oversize /ˈəʊvəsaɪz/)
> ​bigger than the normal size; too big
> ♦ She wore a pair of baggy jeans and an oversized T-shirt.
> ♦ Many children are being taught in oversized classes.

If you don't want that connotation it is better to use "life-size" with a qualifying expression.

- a chair bigger than life-size, a chair much greater than life-size

You can even use this phrase as an adjective.

- Find larger than life size stock images in HD and millions of other royalty-free stock photos, illustrations and vectors in the Shutterstock collection

(https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=bigger+than+life-size)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I might just use a 'towering chair' and skip the 'life' part if there are no better alternatives.

Comment: @grouchdoug Yes, of course, the option I provided is merely one out of several others.